# Camera doesnt follow ball in tube (Blender Game Engine)

Tags: game-engine, physics, camera, logic-bricks

I'm trying to make a game where a ball rolls in a tube and hits several obstacles that triggers sounds.
I vertex-parented my camera to the ball (so it doesnt spin as the ball does)
I have several problems :

1. The inside of the tube doesnt shows in play mode.
2. The camera always goes out of the tube when i move the ball (physics type is rigid body, it shouldnt)
3. The direction of the ball isnt fluid, it seems to block in the turns

[Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwqhIZTalOMbMmhTeURQSXV4WVU/view) the file to understand more clearly.

If you could help... Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to address at least something:

1) Your "tube" material has "backface" enabled, thus now you can't see it from the inside, because  tube's normals are pointing outside. Try to remove backface OR leave backface, but invert normals (in this way you can also see through the tube when looking the whole tube path from outside, to get a bird's eye view, which helps to spot how is working well and where not...

2) the current camera parenting isn't working well: moving the ball (pressing S) it goes behind it at the beginning, but then it goes around it (and something goes out of the tube), then also in front of the ball... I think you should somehow set the position  of the camera to be always behind the ball along the ball direction axis... I don't know how, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked well for the material.
For the camera, I will eventually try with logic bricks, since I don't know how to do it differently.